# Using fsockopen to precompile key jsp pages

Tags: php, fsockopen

So the original problem is that we run an "industry standard" java based web app application, on WebSphere App Servers with around 100 million visits per year. The issue is after a restart of these appservers, we need to hit a few of the key pages so that the main servlets get compiled before we let the public onto them ... otherwise they tend to crash in the initial crush.

On some clusters, its about 6 pages that need to be hit, once for each of 35+ markets.... 200 ish url's!

So the script I am working on has all the hard work done of how to put together all these URL's and at the end of it all is a list of 200 url's in an array... now how to hit them?

We were using CGI for this earlier and it's main problem was that is was synchronous... taking a loooooong time. Now I am trying to make a simple url.php which will hit one single URL which I can then call from JQuery in an asynchronous way. I don't want to hit all 200 at first of course, probably in batchs of 5 should mean a 500% speed increase :)

So onto the url.php . I haven't use php much in the past so sockets is a bit new to me. What I have cobbled together so far is this:

```
function checkUrl($url,$port) {
set_time_limit(20); 
ob_start(); 
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$u = $url; 
$p = $port;

$post = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$post .= "Host: $u\r\n";
$post .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20060308 Firefox/1.5.0.2\r\n";
$post .= "Keep-Alive: 200\r\n";
$post .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";

$sock = fsockopen($u, $p, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$sock) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($sock, $post, strlen($post));
    while (!feof($sock)){
        echo fgets($sock);
    }
    ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

Which works great if the url is simply someserver.somedomain.com but if the is a Uri tapped on the end it fails (e.g. someserver.somedomain.com/gb/en)

As I understand it, all I have done with the code so far is open the socket connection ... but how can I get it to parse the path separately?

The only output I need from this in the end is the HTTP Status code (200, 404, 301 etc) though it is important that it does fetch the complete page first in order for it to be compiled properly.

Comment: seems like SO only shows good related questions after the submit :)

I found a better chunk of code which is now working nicely and will even allow me to seperated some other logic... but now what I have is this:


    function checkUrl($host,$url,$port) {
 $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
 if (!$fp) {
     echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
 } else {
     $out = "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\n";
     $out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
     $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
     fwrite($fp, $out);
     while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
     } 
     fclose($fp);
 }
    }

Comment: Which works great even with some of the more complex links. By echoing the whole thing out I can see I am getting the full content as well as the response headers so its perfect in that respect. Now I only want to return the actual Status Code so if anyone wants to add that example feel free.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but do you have the [curl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) available?  No need to get jQuery in the mix, you can run asynchronous queries straight from PHP with ease.  You'll also be able to control batch size easily, and put in delays and what-not per your needs.  Also I'm not sure why you would need to use a raw socket to hit the JSP pages, hopefully this makes your life easier!

Here's a quick test script I have, based on code from php.net I'm sure:

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://news.php.net/php.general/255000");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://news.php.net/php.general/255001");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
?>
```

Comment: Indeed, CURL ended up to be the best option and immensely useful for my next project too :)

Comment: Glad you liked it.  In general `fsockopen` & `file_get_contents` etc will always be the quickest to implement and contribute to PHP's reputation of being quick to develop with.  Although they can be tweaked with stream contexts & wrappers those options are a somewhat painful alternative to just using curl directly.  Happy hunting on your next project!